# Error: Incorrect number of parameters for function 'ISPICKVAL()'. Expected 2, received 1

Tags: validation-rule

```
AND(
    ISPICKVAL(StageName, "Closed Won"),
    ISPICKVAL(StageName, "Closed Won - Documents Submitted"),
    ISPICKVAL(Job_Type__c, "Solar"),
    ISCHANGED(StageName),
    $RecordType.Name="Solar",
    OR(
        ISBLANK(Text(kW_DC__c),
        ISPICKVAL( Solar_Discounts__c))
    )
)
```

Not sure what is wrong or how to fix it

Answer (score 0):

The error message tells you exactly what's wrong here.

You're trying to call `ISPICKVAL()` somewhere in your formula. It requires 2 parameters (a picklist field and the value you're testing for), and you're only giving it one parameter.

A cursory glance reveals that you have `ISPICKVAL( Solar_Discounts__c)` towards the end of your formula, which is a match for what the error is complaining about.

If `Solar_Discounts__c` is a picklist field, then you need to add your target value to the function call (e.g. `ISPICKVAL(Solar_Discounts__c, 'All of the discounts!')`)